# vuejs input value is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

i'm currently learning vuejs by making a login app however i can access the value of input it gave me undefined , i'm clearly doing something wrong here but i cant find where i'm mistaken here is my code , can u point me to the right direction 
here is the code

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {

      username: "",
      password: ""

    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      console.log(this.username)
    },
  }

})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <p><i>To your Account</i></p>
      <form @submit.prevent="login">
        <input type="text" name="username" v-model="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" value="LOG IN">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: The snippet works as expected.

Comment: its working fine, I putted text and it shows well as expected.

Comment: thank you , indeed its working , dont know what happened ...